# Number of training and test samples in tensor flow code?

Tags: tensorflow

If in tensor flow code number of input sample is 5000000. Does it mean that it training all these samples for training? How can i know the number of samples used for training and test purpose separately?

Comment: Where do you see this number? You are the one that provides the training and test data, so you should know how many samples there are of each.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to choose which ammount of samples are used for training and which for testing. A general approach would be to set a random 70% of samples to train and the remaining 30% to test. This can be done fairly simply as such:

Lets assume you have a dataframe of 5000000 samples named `df`. The `sample()` function from pandas will allow you to select a specified percentage of random samples which can be set aside for training. The remaining 30% will be indexed and used for testing.

```
import pandas as pd

train_set = df.sample(frac=0.7)
test_set = df.loc[~data_.index.isin(train_set.index)]
```

Now you have two dataframes, one for training (3500000 samples) and one for testing (1500000 samples)